# Syncing local git repository to remotes gitlab and Overleaf

Tags: git, gitlab, push, mirroring

I have a local git repository for a LaTeX document. Two remote repositories defined as well:

- one 'origin' that points to a private [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) repository
- and one 'overleaf' that points in an [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) project ([which bases on git too](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/195-new-collaborate-online-and-offline-with-overleaf-and-git-beta))

I set up [mirroring](https://gitlab.com/help/workflow/repository_mirroring) ('push') from gitlab towards Overleaf.
My concern is to have a clean history, of course, and co-work with colleagues that use Overleaf.

- What can go wrong here?
- Are there **do**s and **don't**s?
- Should I only `push` from local to gitlab? Or is it ok to `push` in both remotes?

Comment: Please explain if you vote to close this question.